# Content script triggered for omnibox

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension injects a content script into every page (`"matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]`). The content script will fire a message (`chrome.extension.sendRequest`) to the background page, and the background page registers an event handler:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function (request, sender, callback) {…}
);
```

I have noticed that those events are fired as I start typing in the omnibox – even before I hit Enter to load the destination page.

Scenario:

- Launch Chrome
- Start typing in the omnibox. In fact, as soon as the omnibox has focus, my `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener()` event handler [background.html] is fired.

The weird thing is that the sender.tab.index value is -1, so it doesn’t map to a “real” tab. Also, as I continue switching focus away from, and back to the omnibox, the events keep firing. Each time, sender.tab.index is -1, but sender.tab.id is being incremented by 2 (43, 45, 47, …). This behavior is easily reproducible.

Then, when I actually choose a URL (say, example.com) by hitting Enter in the omnibox, and the page loads in the browser/tab, I get yet another event.  This time, however, sender.tab.index is non-negative – it represents the actual browser tab, and my content script handler can do its work.

Is this behavior – content script being injected into a “phantom” page for omnibox actions – known, and is it documented anywhere?  And what is the proper way for my event handler to handle this? Let’s say my content script handler needs to manipulate the web page. Should I be checking sender.tab.index, and only doing the work if `sender.tab.index != -1`?

Answer (score 1):

Not as much as it is happening. The behavior is expected with prerendered pages but that should be much less frequent. In those cases you can use the [Page Visibility API](http://code.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility.html) in your content script and not send a message to the background page unless the page is visible.

You should also file a [bug report](http://new.crbug.com) for the extreme number of "tabs" the content script is getting injected into.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you’re describing is known as “Chrome Instant” search and it involves Chrome preparing invisible search result tabs and then swapping them in for visible tabs, for faster perceived search results. Chrome also sometimes “pre-renders” other webpages for faster perceived page loads.

Yes, a tab ID of -1 indicates that the tab is currently a phantom tab (not accessible to the user).

I haven’t found any thorough documentation of phantom (pre-rendered) tabs anywhere yet, but there are two events fired when Chrome replaces a normal tab with a pre-rendered tab, and their documentation does mention pre-rendering and Chrome Instant:

- [chrome.tabs.onReplaced](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onReplaced)
- [chrome.webNavigation.onTabReplaced](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onTabReplaced)

Answer (score 0):

Google extension's API is not fully documented, and there are lots of undocumented behaviors.  These events firing from omnibox are no new, and aren't documented either.

I recommend not to automatically inject your content script, but to do it programatically, as a response to chrome.tabs.onUpdated event.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated

It will fire on each url's tab change.  You should listen it in your background.html, and then execute your content script using chrome.tabs.executeScript.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript

In this way you will be able to verify the tab's id and url before executing your content script.

BTW, I assume your match pattern is http://* /*

Comment: Yes on the pattern match (the message editor must have eaten the asterisks.)